How to make custom background like this?

Hi, I'm still wondering how to make a background like the one on the picture, I used the right colour
background: linear-gradient(90deg, #7C84F3 0%, #1522E0 93.74%);
but I don't know how to place the circles in the small container...
I've tried everything, and it seems to work, but on the mobile version they are moving apart


.hire__cta {
  background-color: #181818;
  padding: 130px 20px 130px 20px;
}

.hire-developer-needs__cta {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #7C84F3 0%, #1522E0 93.74%);
  padding: 50px 60px;
  max-width: 1400px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
<section class="hire__cta">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="hire-developer-needs__cta">
      <div class="circle circle-1"></div>
      <div class="circle circle-2"></div>
      <div class="circle circle-3"></div>
      <div class="hire-developer-needs__cta-info">
        <h3 class="hire-developer-needs__cta-text">
          Hire experienced React Developers now for Your Needs!
        </h3>
        <p class="hire-developer-needs__cta-subtext">
          Hire React developers to get the right specialists that will cater to the needs of your project fast. Apply to us, and we’ll get back to you to define all the requirements to candidates.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>




It depends on what you want to achieve exactly. You should be clearer about that.

Add three clip-path divs with position: absolute; to the right of the background. You can then put a gradient on each of these

This can be achieved by using clip-path and position: absolute;
I have attached an example snippet.
position: absolute and right will push the circles to the right of the parent.
Setting an z-index of 99 on the text and lower z-index on the circles will mean the text always appears in front.


.circle{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
    position: absolute;

}

.c1{
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #7C84F3 0%, #1522E0 93.74%);

    right: -100px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.c2{
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #7C84F3 0%, #1522E0 93.74%);

    right: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.c3{
    background: linear-gradient(147deg, #7C84F3 0%, #1522E0 93.74%);

    right: 200px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.hire-developer-needs__cta-info{
z-index: 99;
}

.hire-developer-needs__cta {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, #7C84F3 0%, #1522E0 93.74%);
    padding: 50px 60px;
    max-width: 1400px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.hire__cta {
    background-color: #181818;
    padding: 130px 20px 130px 20px;
}
<section class="hire__cta">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="hire-developer-needs__cta">
      <div class="circle circle-1"></div>
      <div class="circle circle-2"></div>
      <div class="circle circle-3"></div>
      <div class="hire-developer-needs__cta-info">
        <h3 class="hire-developer-needs__cta-text">
          Hire experienced React Developers now for Your Needs!
        </h3>
        <p class="hire-developer-needs__cta-subtext">
          Hire React developers to get the right specialists that will cater to the needs of your project fast. Apply to us, and we’ll get back to you to define all the requirements to candidates.
        </p>
      </div><div  class="circle c1"></div>
      <div class="circle c2"></div>
      <div  class="circle c3"></div>
    
    </div>
  </div>
</section>



This is not a responsive answer.
